# why this unexpected variable change happens?

Tags: c++, variables, methods

```
        #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
const int maxsize=20;
class IntStack{
private:
    int element[maxsize],topindex;
public:
    IntStack(){topindex=-1;}
    int getTI(){
        return topindex;
    }
    int top(){
        if(topindex==-1)
            exit(-1);
        return element[topindex];
    }
    int top(int *t){
        if(topindex==-1)
            return -1;
        t=&element[topindex];
        return 0;
    }
    int pop(){
        if(topindex==-1)
            exit(-1);
        topindex--;
        return element[topindex+1];
    }
    int pop(int *t){
        if(topindex==-1)
            return -1;
        t=&element[topindex];
        topindex--;
        return 0;
    }
    int push(int e){
        if(topindex==19)
            return -1;
        topindex++;
        element[topindex]=e;
        return 0;
    }
    inline int empty(){return topindex==-1;}
    ostream& print(ostream& o){
        for(int i=0;i<=topindex;i++){
            o<<element[i]<<' ';
        }
        return o;
    }
};
ostream& operator <<(ostream& o,IntStack s){ ostream& operator <<(ostream& o,IntStack &s)
    cout<<s.getTI()<<endl; // prints 2
    while(s.empty()==0){
        o<<"index("<<s.getTI()<<")= "<<s.pop()<<endl; //getTI prints 1.
    }
    return o;
}
int main(){
    IntStack s;
    s.push(5);
    s.push(6);
    s.push(7);
    cout<<s; // the indexes should be 2, 1 , 0 but they are 1 0 -1!
    system("pause");
}
```

please compile this, and you just need to read getTI() and pop() methods. in the operator << overloading, we see different values for s.getTI and thats weird!

Comment: Try to come up with a minimal example, maybe a dozen lines.

Answer (score 5):

```
o<<"index("<<s.getTI()<<")= "<<s.pop()<<endl; //getTI prints 1.
```

You are assuming that `s.getTI()` is evaluated before `s.pop()`, which is not necessarily true. The order of evaluation of these operands is completely unspecified and, in fact, the pattern I usually see is roughly right-to-left evaluation.

Do the `s.getTI()` and `s.pop()` evaluations on separate lines of code.

Comment: yes I've tried in separate lines and you are right! but why the order of evaluation of these operands is completely unspecified?? isn't it an  incompetence of thus language??

Comment: @user2038951: No, not really. There's no reason for a language to define the order of operand evaluation. You can get the same result yourself when you want to, and when you don't care (which is most of the time) you don't pay extra for the privilege.